When opening external link, and user goes back, redirect user to my Activity
I have activity in my app, where links to social networks are located. They are opened following way:
context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myURL))

So when user clicks on it, he will be redirected to Facebook, for example (possibly to Facebook app, if installed). However, when user clicks on back (HW button / gesture), this social media app is closed together with my application. Is it possible to be redirected to my activity in that case? So user would return to the place, where he clicked the link. I have tried to create TaskStack, but it does not work.
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myUrl)
val stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java))
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent)
stackBuilder.startActivities()

Thank you for your help.
